# Can this iterative method be implemented recursively?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Main
{
    public static void pyr(int n)
    {      
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
             for(int j = 1;j<=i;j++)
             {  
                  System.out.print("*");
             }
             System.out.println();
        }
    }
 }
```

Can such a code for a pyramid like shape of asteriks be implemented recursively ? if so especially the 2 loops as the first one is for leveling while the second is used to fill each level.

Comment: yep therefore only an answer to the first part ;)

Comment: :) it is kind of but an old one I just started on recursion and thought of converting this to a recursive one but stumbled on the levelling part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes - basically everything iterative can be done recursively, sometimes it is much easier, but more time consuming.

For your question - this does the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    printPyramid(7);
}

public static void printPyramid(int lines)
{
    if (lines > 1)
    {
        printPyramid(lines-1);
    }
    printLine(lines);
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void printLine(int level)
{
    if (level > 0)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
        printLine(level-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: if that answered your question, approve the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> "Any function that can be evaluated by
>   a computer can be expressed in terms
>   of recursive functions without the use
>   of iteration, in continuation-passing
>   style; and conversely any recursive
>   function can be expressed in terms of
>   iteration."
>   Source:
>   http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/tag/recursion/

Edit: added source link.

Comment: Nice quote, but where's it from?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just have a look at the chapter of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration). I've seen a mathematic proof also but I forgot where I can find it.

In your case just use two methods. One prints stars as long as the input parameter is greater 0.

```
public void static printStar(int n) {
  if(n > 0) {
      System.out.print("*");
      --n;
      printStar(n);
  }
}
```

This code handles your inner loop.

```
public void static printPyramid(int n, int start) {
  if(start >= n) {
    return;
  }

  printStar(start);
  ++start;
  printPyramid(n, start);
}
```

This code handles your outer loop. Where start is your i.

Comment: something is missing I think System.out.println(); before print(start); in the second method.so we can start the next print(Star) in a new line. otherwise for n = 5 start (0) it would print ***********